# Is it possible to make text translucent in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, transparency, opacity

I am adding some wx.StaticText objects on top of my main wx.Frame, which already has a background image applied. However, the StaticText always seems to draw with a solid (opaque) background color, hiding the image. I have tried creating a wx.Color object and changing the alpha value there, but that yields no results. Is there any way I can put text on the frame and have the background shine through? And furthermore, is it possible to make the text itself translucent? Thanks.

Comment: Have you asked your question on the wxpython mailing list?  You're more likely to get an authoritative answer there.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need some graphics rendering widget. As far as I know, in wxPython you can use either built-in wxGraphicsContext or pyCairo directly. Cairo is more powerful. However, I don't know the details.

Answer (score 0):

I would try aggdraw into a small canvas.

Any Static Text uses the platform's native label machinery, so you don't get that sort of control over it.